# Should HTML anchors wrap the heading or stand on its own?

Tags: html, accessibility, anchor

There are two ways we've seen people making anchors on a page:

```
<h2>Heading associated with the anchor</h2><a id="anchor"></a>
```

Where the anchor is outside of the associated element, in this case we're jumping to a heading, and the anchor itself has no text.

Or...

```
<a id="anchor"><h2>Heading associated with the anchor</h2></a>
```

Where the anchor wraps the element of the section we're linking, too.

Both work. A link to `https://examplepage.com/page#anchor` works for both.

Do either of these conflict with HTML coding standards?

Do either of these disrupt assistive technology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can disrupt assistive technologies. In your example, when a screen reader navigates to the anchor, it has no deterministic way of knowing that it should read aloud the preceding paragraph.

Also, when you open a URL to `http://somedomain.com/somepath#anchor` the browser will automatically scroll to the element that has `id=anchor`, so it's important to put the anchor on the element that makes sense.

Any element can have an anchoring id, it does not need to be an `<a/>`.

Answer (score 0):

Anchors (without href) [no longer exist in HTML5](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/a.html) as such tag is now used to represent placeholder hyperlinks

> If the `href` attribute is not specified, the element represents a placeholder hyperlink.

You can directly set the `id` attribute on the heading with a `tabindex` attribute for older browser if you want the keyboard sequence to be consistent.

```
<h2 id="anchor" tabindex="-1">Heading associated with the anchor</h2>
```